# Do we have to make any changes to a Springer LaTeX template before submission?

Tags: publications, formatting, latex, springer

The Springer template is by far the most bizarre out of all of the LaTeX templates I've seen so far. There is no problem as long as you stick to the two-column option, but the appearance of the single column option is just crazy.

The main problems are the following

- The right margin being outlandishly wide compared to the left margin.
- Smaller font size in main content
- Bigger font in reference section

These issues *can* be corrected to make the format look identical to the published papers in the same journal. However is it necessary?

I would especially like to know from people who have published papers in Springer who have submitted it using the standard LaTeX template provided by the publishers.

This is particularly about Multimedia Tools and Applications, but I've noticed this problem in other journals sections that use the same template.

Comment: Springer has many templates. Which are you talking about? CCIS? LNCS? Something else?

Comment: @xLeitix: I'm currently focussing on MTAP. Thanks for the clarification; just made the edit. LNCS didn't have this problem the last time I've used it. I had the problem when working with JSPS too, but used the two-column option and had no trouble with it.

Comment: I've used the svjour3 Springer template recently. It does have some weird formatting, but two-column works okay. Do you have to submit in one-column? What do the author's guidelines for your journal say?

Comment: @Ian Same here, I had no issues with JSPS which was two-column, but it is the MTAP which looks so strange with the single column requirement.

Comment: In my experience no changes are needed and these formating issues will be taken care of by the typesetters.

Comment: If you don't like the look while drafting, you can adjust things (for instance, make the margins a more comfortable width), but then leave it up to the publisher's outsourced production team for the rest. Have you checked out the published articles? Looking at a recent one in MTAP with single-column the left and right margins are (to my eye) the same width and the references are in a slightly smaller font than the body text. This was also the case for something I published using svjour3 (https://doi.org/10.1007/s10485-015-9400-4)

Comment: @DavidRoberts Please don't adjust the geometry of the page to your liking. It will change where the lines cut, potentially causing multiple overfull and underfull boxes, especially if you are using long equations, graphs or table. It's my job to check the layout of article and authors regularly put their source in A4 (while we publish in a format close to A5), giving me a lot a work to cut their equation correctly. Use the template as is and don't worry about the margins.

Comment: @Luris I did say "while drafting". I wasn't clear that I meant that for submission any adjustments to the results of using the template as-is should be left in the hands of the production team, rather than leaving it to them to fix any alterations back to how it needs to be. It would be nice if the output pdf was the size of the printed page, assuming the journal has a print copy, so that the result could be seen before proof (or publication) stage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. I don't recommend changes to the template. That is because the journal can easily update the template to the style they prefer for publication. Your changes to the template won't affect the eventual look of the manuscript.

Answer (score 4):

Please, don't adjust the geometry of the page to your liking. It will change where the lines cut, potentially causing multiple overfull and underfull boxes, especially if you are using long equations, graphs or table. Use the template as is and don't worry about the margins.

The only reason I see to change the template would be if the template is not adapted to the final version. But in that case, it's the editor's problem, not yours.

Source: It's my job to check the layout of article and sometime authors put their source in A4 (while we publish in a format close to A5), giving me a lot a work to cut their A4-wide equations and tables correctly.